# Saving datauri to png file using PHP - creates empty png file

Tags: php, image, base64, png

I have been trying a dozen ways to save a dataurl generated from an svg to my server.  This code seems like it should be working based on other threads I've read here but for some reason it just creates a .png file with 0kb.  I went ahead and just copy/pasted the dataurl right into my script to avoid any data being sent to php issues right now, I just want to see the php create the image correctly.  Here's my code:

```
$img="data:image/png;base64,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...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";

$filedata = substr($img, strpos($img,",")+1);

file_put_contents("testfile2.png", base64_decode($filedata));

echo "file created";
```

Here's the jquery code that's generating the data.  I just copy it from the alert to test in this script:

```
$("#testclick").click(function() {

var svg = document.getElementById("map").innerHTML; // or whatever you call it
//alert(svg);
 $('#load-target').html(svg);

var canvas = $('#load-target svg')[0];
try {
  svgAsDataUri(canvas, null, function(uri) {
  var image = new Image();
        image.src = uri;
        image.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.download = name;
        alert(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
        a.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        }

    //alert(uri);
    $.post("http://www.srqnews.com/maps/create.php",
    {
        type:"PNG",
        datauri:uri
    },
    function(data,status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
  });
} catch(err) {
  alert(err.message);
}

});
```

Comment: b64_decode returns boolean FALSE on failure, which would output as a zero-length string. try `$data = base64_decode(...); if ($data === false) { die("b64 data is corrupted"); }`

Comment: So my jquery must be creating bad data. Editing in the jquery code

Comment: could be as simple as your substr operation going too far and slicing of the first char of the b64 data.

Comment: I've tried plugging in just the text after the comma and not doing the substr op with same results.  I'm guessing my jquery is causing the bad data somehow.  Ugh, just new to this stuff so taking me forever to get it right.